# Tkinter and random numbers

Tags: python, random, tkinter

Newish to programming and just learning Tkinter. Wrote this based on an example in Alan Gauld's online Tutorial. I am expecting a random number between 1 and 10 to be put into the label, but I am getting what seems to a be a random number between 40million and 50 million, followed by "getRandomNumber". The code:

```
import random
from tkinter import *

class randomNumberApp:
    def __init__(self, parent=0):
        self.mainWindow = Frame(parent)
        self.fTop = Frame(self.mainWindow)
        self.fTop.pack(fill="both")
        self.lInfo = Label(self.fTop, text="Your number is:")
        self.lInfo.pack(side="left")
        self.lScore = Label(self.fTop, text=self.getRandomNumber)
        self.lScore.pack(side="left")
        self.mainWindow.pack(fill="both")

    def getRandomNumber():
        ability = random.randint(1,10)
        return ability

# top level
top = Tk()
app = randomNumberApp(top)
top.mainloop()
```

Any help would be great

Comment: Someone closed this with the `typographical error` reason. Can someone explain?

Comment: @sshashank124 I didn't but may be because of `text=self.getRandomNumber`

Comment: @thefourtheye, Actually in Tkinter, that is correct, contrary to one's expectations, using `()` is incorrect.

Comment: I asked the Question and I am not really sure what the problem is (both with the code and the closing). could someone explain? Cheers

Comment: @sshashank124: you are incorrect. Using `()` is often incorrect when using functions as the value of the `command` attribute, but this usage is in a label where using `()` to call the function and use the returned value is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a label, and for it's value you are giving a function. You don't want to use a function as the text of the label, you want to *call* the function and use what the function returns for the label.

Instead of this:

```
self.lScore = Label(self.fTop, text=self.getRandomNumber)
```

... you need to do this:

```
self.lScore = Label(self.fTop, text=self.getRandomNumber())
```

Also, if `getRandomNumber` is to be a method, you need to defined it to have the parameter `self`, as in the following example:

```
class randomNumberApp:
    ...
    def getRandomNumber(self):
        ...
```

Answer (score 3):

This works:

Changed to "text=self.getRandomNumber()" and indented "def getRandomNumber(self):" because it is more like the code from the OP.

```
import random
from tkinter import *

class randomNumberApp:
    def __init__(self, parent=0):
        self.mainWindow = Frame(parent)
        self.fTop = Frame(self.mainWindow)
        self.fTop.pack(fill="both")
        self.lInfo = Label(self.fTop, text="Your number is:")
        self.lInfo.pack(side="left")
        self.lScore = Label(self.fTop, text=self.getRandomNumber())
        self.lScore.pack(side="left")
        self.mainWindow.pack(fill="both")

    def getRandomNumber(self):
        ability = str(random.randint(1,10))
        return ability

# top level
top = Tk()
app = randomNumberApp(top)
top.mainloop()
```

Comment: The other possible solution is to leave `getRandomNumber`, but give it the `self` parameter.

Comment: That just reproduced the problem for me.

Comment: Then you did something wrong. You still have to _call_ the function, but it can be a method on the class (with the `self` parameter and properly indented) or it can be a global function (without self, and with no extra indentation).

Comment: There were two changes needed - add self to the getRandomNumber method and adding parentheses to the call.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I guess I wasn't precise enough in my first comment -- the parenthesis are required in this case, and then you can either add the `self` parameter, or do what you did and move the function outside the scope of the class.